# PHP, Como pedir una contraseña y validar dentro de un IF (SIMPLE)

Tags: php, formularios, condiciones

Tengo una variable que devuelve: (ENPLAZO, FUERADEPLAZO), quiero que en caso de que sea FUERADEPLAZOpida una contraseña, y que en caso de que esa contraseña sea la correcta continue por el if del ENPLAZO.

Ejemplo  de mi codigo:

```
        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
                
            if($row[PLAZO_DEVOLUCION] == 'EN_PLAZO'){
            $pass='1234';}
            if($row[PLAZO_DEVOLUCION] == 'FUERA_DE_PLAZO') {
                
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("¡ATENCION! Pedido fuera de plazo de devolución.")';
                echo '</script>';
                
                ?>
                <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="#">
                        Contraseña para acceder :
                        <input type="password" id="contra" name="contra" size="10" required />
                        <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="enviar"/>
                </form>
                
<?php
}
            if(isset($_POST['contra'])){
            $pass=$_POST['contra'] ?? null;
            if ($pass!='1234') {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("¡ATENCION! Contraseña Incorrecta.")';
            echo '</script>';
            }}
            
            if ($pass=='1234'){ //aqui seguiria con mas codigo que no es necesario para enseñar el error}

       }
```

Y asi estaria bien tambien? esq me da error.

Comment: Tu primer condicional es erróneo, con un solo signo de `=` lo que haces es **una asignación**, no una comparación, debes ponerlo así: `If ($answer == 'PERMISO')  {?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu primer condicional es erróneo, con un solo signo de `=` lo que haces es **una asignación**, no una comparación.

Por otra parte, deberías controlar que el formulario fue enviado, o te expondrías a casos de *`Undefined index`*.

Te aconsejaría además que no abuses de la mezcla de bloques, la cual produce un código confuso, difícil de analizar, de leer y de depurar. En muchos casos puedes resolver mejor con un `echo`, permaneciendo así dentro del mismo bloque php.

Así debería funcionar:

```
<?php

if ($answer == 'PERMISO')  {
    echo "<p>Tienes acceso</p>";
}
else
{  
?>
<p> no tienes permiso </p>

<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="#" >
 Contraseña para acceder :
 <input type="password" id="contra" name="contra" size="10 required"/>
 <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="enviar"  />
</form>
<?php
}

$pass=$_POST['contra'] ?? null;
if ($pass=='1234') {
    echo "<p>Tienes acceso </p>";
}
?>
```